# try to fetch data from api in angular but get error that Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

My Angular version is 16.0.1 and I try fetch data from Api

https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees

this is my **Model**

```
export interface Emploee {
employee_name: string;
}
```

My **service** is

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Emploee } from '../models/emploee.model';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmploeeService {
_url = "https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees"
constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
getEmploee():Observable<Emploee[]>{
  return this.http.get<Emploee[]>(this._url)
} }
```

And my **component.ts** is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Emploee } from '../models/emploee.model';
import { EmploeeService } from '../services/emploee.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-emploee',
templateUrl: './emploee.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./emploee.component.scss']
    })
export class EmploeeComponent {
 emploee$! : Emploee[];
ngOnInit() {
this.fetchEmploee();
   }
constructor(private emploeeService:EmploeeService){}
fetchEmploee(){
this.emploeeService.getEmploee().subscribe(res=> this.emploee$ = res);
   }
   }
```

And this is my **component.html**

```
<p *ngFor="let emploee of emploee$">{{emploee.employee_name }}</p>
```

when I run my project i get this error

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only > supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays

How can I resolve that?
also my project is in this link :https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xuvgju?embed=1&file=src%2Fmain.ts

and picture from postman is:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, normally we use the `$` prefix to indicate an Observable. You are using it on an array, which is confusing for anyone else looking at your code.

I thought you were missing the async pipe because I thought that the emploee$ variable was an observable.

But the actual problem is that the data being returned is not of the shape you have defined.

If you look at the data shape, it contains much more data then just the `Emploee` data.

Consider updating your interface to match the data shape.

Alternately, you could modify your `getEmploee` to access just the "data" property which seems to hold the actual employee data.

```
getEmploee():Observable<Emploee[]>{
  return this.http.get(this._url).pipe(
          map(value => value.data)
  );
}
```

I have a working Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-5uprkt

For more information on RxJS, check out this video: https://youtu.be/vtCDRiG__D4

Comment: thank you so much,what about if my json data return the same as "my data":[...], in above core my json is  directly the same as array and data start with bracket "[" , but how can I map data if data start with "my data" : [...]

Comment: Could you elaborate on the question? Or better yet, fork the stackblitz, use it to illustrate the issue, and post the link to the forked stackblitz here.

Comment: the link that add new component is in this url :https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xuvgju also edit my question again

Comment: That code looks like it is OK ... but I can't run it because I don't have the end point.